# convert pdf to png deterministically or test sequences of bytes are almost identical

Tags: python, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, wand

I'm using [Wand](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/) to convert pdf to png, and I'd like to ensure in my tests that the sequence of bytes resulting from the transformation of a pdf input, yields always the same sequence of bytes on the png output,  given a set of conversion parameters.

That happens unfortunately not to be the case, and digging a little bit into why, it seems Wand has not the ability to save png without the current date set (https://github.com/dahlia/wand/issues/369)

I could still test with subprocess using imagemagick directly with the `-define png:exclude-chunks=date` flag that apparently doesn't set a date on the png created, but maybe there's an another, more interesting and more accurate way.

I'm currently using `SequenceMatcher` to test the outputs, which is ok but determining what level the test should pass is somewhat arbitrary and I'm not happy about that.

```
@pytest.fixture
def simplebase64pdf(request):
    with open(os.path.join(request.fspath.dirname, 'data/dummy.pdf'), 'rb') as simplepdf:
        pdfbytes = simplepdf.read()
    pdfstrb64 = bytes_to_b64str(pdfbytes)
    assert b64str_to_bytes(pdfstrb64) == pdfbytes
    return pdfstrb64

def test_stability(simplebase64pdf):
    stable = []
    for i in range(2):
        img = get_image_from_pdf(b64str_to_bytes(simplebase64pdf))[0]
        stable.append(img)
        # with open(str(i)+'.png', 'wb') as f:
        #     f.write(img)
    x = SequenceMatcher(None, stable[0], stable[1]).ratio()
    assert x > 0.999
```

Comment: Yes, what you’ve written is pretty arbitrary. You want to test “are these the same file except for the DATE chunk”, but instead you’re checking “are these the same file except for 0.1% of the bytes”. That could fail for a tiny PNG, or a PNG with more metadata that you don’t care about but later version of the lib does, while succeeding for a huge PNG even though the image chunks aren’t the same. So, you’re right to not be happy.

Comment: Ideally you’d want to use a PNG chunk parser so you can write an assertion that means what you’re asking: same chunks in same order and all but those in a blacklist (maybe just `DATE`) have the same contents. But that may be more work than you want. A simpler alternative might be to read the images in (with wand, or with a completely different library like Pillow) and test the attributes of the resulting image object, but that makes the test more abstract and harder to prove that it really means what you want.

Comment: Or, for a quick&dirty hack that’s a little nicer than what you’re doing now, if you can get the actual diffs, you can verify that there’s only one diff, it’s exactly the length of a DATE chunk, even that the differing bytes are something you can parse as a datetime and they’re both within some expected time range. There’s still a tiny chance that two images will differ in a way that happens to exactly pass that test, but it’ll probably never happen, and it’s probably good enough for a unit test as long as there’s a comment to explain that possibility.

Comment: You might just use a tool that extracts the image from the PDF and then convert that. See pdfimages, https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwir056kgabaAhWIhFQKHeg2DeUQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPdfimages&usg=AOvVaw1CyFa7AMV3nhofpK-Jg1ks.

Comment: @fmw42 I'm not interested in extracting images from pdf :) I just transform pdf in images which is slightly different !

Comment: `@euro` I understand. But converting a PDF to a raster image is dependent upon the colorspace and the density you assign. So if you want to get the very same image from the PDF, that is hard, especially from Imagemagick (Wand). That is why I suggested just extracting the image from the PDF and converting that to whatever format you want. If I misunderstand your problem, my apologies. I just was suggesting an alternate that might avoid issue.

Comment: @fmw42 mm seems it's me that misunderstood what you meant, I thought you wanted me to extract the images embedded in the pdf ! my apologies, will try that as well, worth a shot

Comment: `@euri10` Yes, I was suggesting you extract the raster image from within the vector PDF before converting to PNG, if it is not already png. The tool I have used is pdfimages, which is available for windows and unix. You may still need to use Imagemagick to exclude the date chunk. I do not know the capabilities of pdfimages in that regard.